# Frequencies of elements in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

I have a numpy array `output` of shape `(1000,4)`. It is an array which contains 1000 quadruples with no repetitions and they are ordered (i.e. an element is [0,1,2,3]). I want to count how many times I got all possible quadruples. More practically, I use the following code:

```
comb=np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(32),4)))
def counting(comb, output):
    k=0
    n_output=np.zeros(comb.shape[0])
    for i in range(comb.shape[0]):
        k=0
        for j in range(output.shape[0]):
            if (output[j]==comb[i]).all():
                k+=1
        n_output[i]=k
    return n_output
```

How can I optimize the code? At the moment it takes 30 s to run

Comment: Try to come up with a method that does not involve nested for loops.

Comment: Can you add the output array also?

Comment: The output array is populated randomly according to a specific distribution (more complicated than the uniform or the gaussian one). So, it's something like: [[1,2,4,25],...[16,18,20,30]...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is inefficient for 2 reasons:

- the complexity of the algorithm is `O(n^2)`;
- it makes use of (slow CPython) loops.

You write a simple `O(n)` algorithm using Python sets (still with a loop) since `output` does not have any repetitions. Here is the result:

```py
def countingFast(comb, output):
    k=0
    n_output=np.zeros(comb.shape[0])
    tmp = set(map(tuple, output))
    for i in range(comb.shape[0]):
        n_output[i] = int(tuple(comb[i]) in tmp)
    return n_output
```

On my machine, using the described input sizes, the original version takes 55.2 seconds while this implementation takes 0.038 second. This is roughly **1400 times faster**.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a boolean array representing if the sequence you want to check is equal to a given row in your array. As numpy's boolean arrays can be summed, you could then use this result to get the total number of matching rows.

A basic approach could look like this (including sample data generation):

```
import numpy as np

# set seed value of random generator to fixed value for repeatable output
np.random.seed(1234)

# create a random array with 950x4 elements
arr = np.random.rand(950, 4)

# create a 50x4 array with sample sequence
# this is the sequence we want to count in our final array
sequence = [0, 1, 2, 3]
sample = np.array([sequence, ]*50)

# stack arrays to create sample data with 1000x4 elements
arr = np.vstack((arr, sample))

# shuffle array to get a random distribution of random sample data and known sequence
np.random.shuffle(arr)

# check for equal array elements, returns a boolean array
results = np.equal(sequence, arr)

# sum the boolean array to get the number of total occurences per axis
# as the sum is the same for all columns, we just need to get the first element at index 0
occurences = np.sum(results, axis=0)[0]

print(occurences)
# --> 50
```

You need to call the required lines for each of sequence you are interested in. Therefore, it would be useful to write a function like this:

```
def number_of_occurences(data, sequence):
    results = np.equal(sequence, data)
    return np.sum(results, axis=0)[0]
```